# Excel 2013: My Cell Styles menu gone messy after running a macro

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

[This is the picture of Cell style menu problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2620.png)

After running a macro to copy data from one workbook to another, my cell style menu became blank.

This is the code of my macro:

```
Sheets("Calofic-Daily Sale Report").Select
Range("E1:W67").Copy

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim folderPath As String

folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FilePath = Dir(folderPath & "\Today, Todate & Year to date Dispatch of Calofic ******.xlsx")

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & FilePath)

Set ws = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

wbk.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are pasting values only.  You need to copy formats too.

Comment: I have the problem with the "Cell Style menu", as you can see in the picture, after running this marcos. I have tried to paste both Values and Format but the menu didn't come back to normal.

Comment: Have you tried a test opening a clear workbook?  Your .xlsx can be corrupted.

Comment: What you have there in the cell style menu is the opposite of "blank". There are much many custom styles. But the code you have shown cannot be blamed for this. There are no `.Styles.Add ` codelines present. So the reason for this must be other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have corrupt styles, regardless of which you need to clean your file. Two options below.

***1. Free tool***

Suggest you download and run XLGeek's free [xlStylesTool](https://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/net4-0-version-of-the-xlstylestool-is-now-available/). A brilliant utility which is much better than the manual method below.

***2. Edit xml using zip***
Edig the worbook in [*zip* mode](http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1121357&s=d902bfcf44ece4e363e2ae9f8f63405c&p=4286836&viewfull=1#post4286836). Steps for doing so added below in case link ever disappears

- Change the extension from xlsm or xlsb to zip
- Open the zip file, navigate to the xl folder, and copy styles.xml to a convenient location
- Open styles.xml with a text editor. Locate the open and close cellstyles tags, and delete them and everything between.
- Save the file, and copy back to the zip file
- Restore the original extension.